# TypeScript: Generic type to enforce values from const assertion

Tags: typescript

How can I write a **generic type** which can be used for all const assertions to enforce their respective values?

#### Code

```js
const GENDER = {
  male: 'm',
  female: 'f',
} as const;

type GenderType = typeof GENDER[keyof typeof GENDER];

// enforces userGender to be either 'm' of 'f'
let userGender: GenderType;

userGender = 'f'; // valid
userGender = 'm'; // valid
userGender = 'o'; // invalid
```

How can I generalise it such that it can be used with all const assertions?

```js
// generalise the boilerplate of
// typeof SOMETHING[keyof typeof SOMETHING]

type GenderType = ValueType<GENDER>;
type FooType = ValueType<FOO>;
type BarType = ValueType<BAR>;
type BazType = ValueType<BAZ>;
```

Comment: You can make a type alias that works like `ValueType<typeof FOO>` but no `ValueType<FOO>`, because `FOO` is a value but generics take types and not values.

Comment: So what do you want to see as an answer here?  If `type ValueType<T> = T[keyof T]` and then `ValueType<typeof GENDER>` is okay, great.  If you insist on `ValueType<GENDER>` then the answer here is just "no, this can't be done" and I can write up an explanation for why.  Let me know which way to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

Use a generic type that accepts the **type** of the object literal.

```js
// ===== const assertion ===== //

const GENDER = {
  male: 'm',
  female: 'f',
} as const;

// ===== generic solution ===== //

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]

// ====== generic usage ====== //

type GenderType = ValueOf<typeof GENDER>;

// enforces userGender to be either 'm' or 'f'
let userGender: GenderType;

userGender = 'f'; // valid
userGender = 'm'; // valid
userGender = 'o'; // invalid

// === more usage examples === //

type FooType = ValueOf<typeof FOO>;
type BarType = ValueOf<typeof BAR>;
type BazType = ValueOf<typeof BAZ>;
```